# Using ore.groupApply with quantile function producing odd R data type

Tags: r, quantile

I believe I might be using the quantile() function wrong inside an ore.groupApply() but cannot figure out what is going wrong.  If I use median() instead everything works as I expect it to.  But with quantile() I'm getting back a data structure that does not let me access the 5 individual numbers for each entry.  Here is my R code:

```
quant_results <- ore.groupApply( endOfTestBuckets, 
                                 INDEX=endOfTestBuckets$compositeIndex,
                                 function(dat) {
                                   quantile( dat$TOTALCOUNT);
                                 }
                               );
return (ore.pull(quant_results));
```

I am grouping based on the compositeIndex field, and calculating the quantile of the TOTALCOUNT field.  I then pull the results from ORE into R.  Here is an example:

```
quant_results  Large list (159173 elements...)
 100_1013382: Named num [1:5] 0 10 20 30 40
 .. - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "0%" "25%" "50%" "75" ...
 etc.
```

I can get at the composite index find.  For example, names( quant_results[1]) is "100_1013382".  But no matter what I do, I cannot get at the numbers 0, 10, 20, 30 and 40.  In fact, typeof( quant_results[1]) is a list, and length( quant_results[1]) is 1.  And if I sub-index, such as [1][1] it does not help matters any.

As I said, if I use median() instead, then I can get to the median value of each entry.  So I think the issue is with quantile() returning a list of numbers.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it.  You have to use an odd double-bracket notation.  [[1]][[3]] for example gets you the median value (the third numeric) of the first entry.